# Text file as single string in PHP code

Tags: php

my text file is like this:

> atagatatagatagtacataacta\n
>   actatgctgtctgctacgtccgta\n
>   ctgatagctgctcgctactacgat\n
>   gtcatgatctgatctacgatcaga\n

I need this file in single string or in single line in both same and reverese order like this:

> atagatatagatagtacataactaactatgctgtctgctacgtccgtactgatagctgctcgctactacgatgtcatgatctgatctacgatcaga

and  "reverese" (for which I didn't write code because I need help ).
I am using:

```
<?php
    $re = "/[AG]?[AT][AT]GAGG[ATC]GC[GA]?[ATGC]/"; 

    $str = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
    trim($str);

    preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you use preg_match? Just remove the newline characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove spaces and newlines using `preg_replace`, and you can reverse a string using `strrev`.

```
$yourString = "atagatatagatagtacataacta\n actatgctgtctgctacgtccgta\n ctgatagctgctcgctactacgat\n gtcatgatctgatctacgatcaga\n";    
$stringWithoutSpaces = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $yourString);
$stringReversed = strrev($stringWithoutSpaces);
echo $stringReversed;
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

**Explanation:** 
With `preg_replace` you replace any character in `$yourString` with an empty string `""` that matches the search pattern `"/\s+/"`. The `\s` in the search pattern stands for any whitespace character (tab, linefeed, carriage return, space, formfeed), the `+` is there to match also multiple whitespace characters, not just one.

Comment: By the way, in your example you use `/n` as newlines, which will not work, you have to use `\n`. I made an update in my example to correct this.